# How javascript engine detects DOM changes?

Tags: javascript

For example,

```
const elem = document.getElementById('myElem')
elem.style.height = '300px'
```

How does js engine detect that the `elem` has been changed and triggers the repaint of the document?

**Context**

This question came to my mind because I am working with angular and when changing variables related to the view from the controller, the change detection gets triggered and the view is updated. Therefore, I want to know if there is any strategy to detect changes in the js engine that is activated when we update DOM through the DOM API.
Thanks

Comment: The JS engine tells the DOM to change the element. Then the DOM knows and the render process does its stuff.

Comment: The DOM APIs are part of the browser, so it implicitly "knows" when an element has been updated. Your question asks how the **JavaScript** engine detects DOM changes, but the text of the question is different and seems to ask how the browser knows to update the window.

Comment: I think depends on your DOM element if it can listen in it's content changes.

Answer (score 2):

It uses the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to monitor changes to the DOM. From the documentation:

> The MutationObserver interface provides the ability to watch for
>   changes being made to the DOM tree. It is designed as a replacement
>   for the older Mutation Events feature which was part of the DOM3
>   Events specification.

This [article](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-tracking-changes-in-the-dom-using-mutationobserver-86adc7446401) also provides a good overview of how this is achieved, with some code samples.

Here is a code sample from the documentation showing how the engine observes the DOM for changes. You can modify this to suit your case.

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: This is useful information but I don't think it's what the question is about. The OP seems to be asking how the browser knows to repaint the window.

Comment: @Pointy - he wants to know how the engine detects changes, which is what my answer addresses.Read the question again :)

Comment: "How does js engine or the browser APIs detect that the elem has been changed and need to be repainted?"

Comment: @Pointy - key word being "detect"

Comment: Of course the title of the question is in conflict so it's really unclear; as I said, you provided useful information.

Comment: @Nick your answer not answers my question i want to know, for exmaple, when you save a reference of a DOM elem into a variable and change the properties of that element how the js engine or the browser knows to re paint the document.

Comment: @ajuni880 Maybe your question is lost in translation. The js engine needs to detect that the change has happened. When you change the elements attribute, the mutationobserver is "alerted" to this change and invokes a callback function. The callback function then runs and can e.g repaint. i have edited my answer with  the example code from the Mozilla documentation about this.

Comment: @Nick A `MutationObserver` is one possible way a _programmer_ might detect changes that have happened to the DOM, but it is not how the _engine_ detects changes. The latter doesn't have much to do with JavaScript, other than what's in the JavaScript web API specifications that the vendor must conform to.

Answer (score 1):

The [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property is an instance of the [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) class, which makes use of the same [internal logic](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#set-a-css-declaration) when either [`setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) is called or when a value is assigned to one of its CSS declaration properties.

The vendor can then implement the internal logic however they need to in order to schedule repainting and other dependent behavior, as long as they conform to the constraints enumerated in [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#the-cssstyledeclaration-interface), which only *suggests* one possible implementation for the internal logic.